# The Twelve Disciples?

Tags: john, matthew

There's another post (currently on hold) by a new site participant, concerning "the twelve disciples," and this got me wondering if that's only an assumption? That is, were "the twelve" actually disciples before becoming apostles?

The English word "disciple" is our more common reading of the Greek "mathEtou," which is from "manthanO" (#3129) "to learn. That is, were "the twelve" ever just pupils of Christ, or did He call them, as apostles, to be apostles? Some might point to Mat 10:42 and John 8:31 as evidence of their "discipleship" status, but that's reading a lot into those two verses; not a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site [tour]. Also, (I know this is a question, but I see you have made a few answers too) check out [what we are looking for in answers](https://goo.gl/wCxRAv) and the [FAQs](https://goo.gl/j8EfsB). My apologies if it feels like we have been tough on you around here. We usually are better about welcoming new users and directing them to these resources, but it appears you may have been missed. Hopefully that gives some context to why we do what we do here. And Welcome again!

Comment: @robin  Questions are supposed to be based on a text of Scripture according to their rules. So structure the question in such a way that if seeks the question from a portion of Scripture

Comment: @robin In Isaiah 8:16, the Spirit of Christ is speaking about Christ. He says "Bind the testimony among my disciples and I will wait for the Lord who hides his face from the house of Jacob"

Comment: This prophecy foretells that the religious leaders and the masses would be blinded to the testimony of Jesus. That the only people who will understand it are his DISCIPLES !!

Comment: I think you will find that "disciple" (μαθητής) and "apostle" (ἀπόστολος) were used somewhat interchangeably by the evangelists when referring to "the twelve".  For example, Matthew refers to the 12 "disciples" in 10:1 and then calls them "apostles in 10:2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is safe to say that "disciple" (μαθητής) and "apostle" (ἀπόστολος) were used somewhat interchangeably by the Evangelists when referring to "the twelve".  "Disciple" may not always refer to an "apostle", but it quite frequently does.  For example:

**Matthew 10:1-2**

> *And when he had called unto him his twelve disciples, he gave them power against unclean spirits, to cast them out, and to heal all manner of sickness and all manner of disease. Now the names of the twelve apostles are these ...*

Comment: This question has been closed by committee, but since I did appreciate and accept your good response, I was just wondering if it could be explained why it was considered to be "off-topic" since your answer was directly from a specific verse, which I'd been inadvertently overlooking?